# Angular + Joomla CMS - keep the same session

Tags: angular

I work on Angular app which works with Joomla CMS site (Apache server). I've created REST API for the purpose but I've encountered some issue with it and the issue is, every time I make a call to the REST API, say, http.post() it creates a new session but I need to keep the same one. Is there any ability to keep the same Apache session? How to pass the same cookie in HTTP request header to the server?

```
 this.http.post( this.appService.buildApiUrl( this.appService.cartApiUrl.getCart ) + `?${this.appService.getTimeToken()}` , {}, this.appService.buildHeaders() ).subscribe( cart => { });
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments so others visitors may read it. Thanks